# Get all "active" attributes taxonomies attached to products in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I want to get all "active" attributes list that attached to the products,

so if the attribute exists, but don't attach to any products don't display.

I can display all attributes as dropdown like this:

```
$attributes =  wc_get_attribute_taxonomies();

if($attributes) {
    echo '<select name="all-attributes" id="all-attributes">';
    foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {
        echo '<option value="' . $attribute->attribute_name . '">' . $attribute->attribute_label . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
}
```

But this way I'm getting all attributes, even non active attributes is not attached.

How to get all **active** product attributes taxonomies attached to products in WooCommerce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all **active** product attributes taxonomies *(attached a least to a product)* you will need a custom simple sql query as follow *(embedded in a php function)*:

```
function wc_get_active_attribute_taxonomies() {
    global $wpdb;

    return $wpdb->get_results( "
        SELECT DISTINCT  wat.*, tt.taxonomy
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies wat
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy tt
            ON tt.taxonomy = CONCAT('pa_', wat.attribute_name)
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships tr
            ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
        WHERE tt.count > 0
    " );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**USAGE** *(based on your code)*:

Just replace:

```
$attributes = wc_get_attribute_taxonomies();
```

by:

```
$attributes = wc_get_active_attribute_taxonomies();
```

> **Note:** This query output, includes additionally the "taxonomy" argument.

Comment: thanks, but I insert this code in hook action woocommerce_before_shop_loop and getting only first attribute and its terms. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you didn't understand me. I mean I want to display all attributes that "active", does this make sense?

Comment: @AkForDev Or you can send me a private message from my profile twitter link too

Comment: I will write you tomorrow in your contact form